# The program dotnet.exe' has exited with code 0 - How to change netcore version

Tags: json, .net

I've got an application that's recently started failing with the above error. It used to work in the past. My version of dotnet is 7.0.200

In my bin/Debug folder the version specified is netcoreapp3.1. I've tried removing this and rebuilding but it goes back to 3.1.

How do I update the app to use 7.0.200 or do I need to install version 3.1 and use a global.json file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your project file look like? I suspect that's what's specifying netcoreapp3.1 as the target framework.

Comment: Thanks Jon, that looks like the issue.